# Loading controllers after restructuring the App/Controllers directory

Tags: php

I have controllers saved to their corresponding sub-directory at the App/Controller directory of my project,

ex.

1.App/Controller/Common for header, footer, home, top_column, left column.

2.App/Controller/User for user, user-permisson.

so on and so forth.

The App/Controller directory remains unchanged but I have different sub-folders for every controller.

To load these controllers, I guess I'll first need to explode the path, get rid of the sub-directory name and then look for the controller in the App/Controller's directory and if found instantiate it.

This below is the rough draft of the code I worked on to check if the above said works or not

```
<?php
$path = 'common/Left_Column';

$result = explode("/", $path);
array_shift($result);
$result = implode("/", $result);

echo $result; // Displays Left_Column
echo '<br>';

$file = 'App/Controller/' . $path . '.php';
echo $file; // Displays App/Controller/common/Left_Column.php
echo '<br>';

$class = $result;
echo $class; // Displays Left_Column

$controller = new $class(); // Error: Fatal error: Class 'Left_Column' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\w3school\index.php on line 19
```

It's working but the last line where I try to instantiate the class I get this error "Error: Fatal error: Class 'Left_Column' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\w3school\index.php on line 19".

Why isn't the class Left_Column found?

**Edit**: Spelt column as coulmn, changed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to add this line before to call your class constructor ?

```
 require_once $file;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's called Left_Co**lu**mn and you have a typo?

Comment: I am not good with spelling and I have named both my controller and class as Left_Coulmn .... No the error isn't due to the typo but sorry for the spelling mistake.